# How can I avoid zero values in an aggregate?

Tags: sql, sum, where-clause

I have a query which is pulling back data correctly, but about a quarter of the lines of data are unnecessary because they have 0 in the primary data field.  Here is the line I wrote to create that primary data field.  How can I exclude any case where the output value for amort_FY2020 is 0?

```
sum(case when f.sales_revenue_period_calendar_sid in ('20200101',
                                                      '20200201',
                                                      '20200301',
                                                      '20200401',
                                                      '20200501',
                                                      '20200601',
                                                      '20200701',
                                                      '20200801', 
                                                      '20200901',           
                                                      '20201001',
                                                      '20201101',
                                                      '20201201') 
         then f.sales_revenue_before_tax_usd_amount 
         else 0 end) as amort_FY2020
```

Comment: Please show us the entire query, not just a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, you can use:

```
having amort_FY2020 <> 0
```

Or may may need to repeat the expression:

```
sum(case when f.sales_revenue_period_calendar_sid in ('20200101','20200201','20200301','20200401','20200501','20200601','20200701','20200801','20200901','20201001','20201101','20201201')
         then f.sales_revenue_before_tax_usd_amount else 0
    end) <> 0
```